# My cookie is not working after redirecting to mobile website

Tags: php, cookies, mobile

My website has two versions, one for desktop and one for mobile. (website.com / m.website.com).

I use a PHP script to redirect my incoming mobile traffic to the mobile version of my website.
For some reason, I need to know the traffic source whithin the mobile version.

To do so I use a script to set a cookie with the traffic source name, before the mobile redirection.

However I can't access the cookie with the mobile version. It seems like its not set.

```
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$refData = parse_url($ref);

if($refData['host'] == 'www.traffic_source_1.com') {
  setcookie("traffic_source_1", 1, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
}

// Redirect to mobile version
```

When I try to access the cookie within the mobile version I get a "not working" result.

```
 if(isset($_COOKIE["traffic_source_1"])) {
     echo "working";
  } else {
      echo "not working";
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

Replaced

```
setcookie("traffic_source_1", 1, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
```

To

```
setcookie("traffic_source_1", 1, time() + (86400 * 30), "/",".website.com");
```

It's working with a test cookie. However when I try to include this line into my condition it doesn't. (The condition parameters are working).

Comment: you need to set the cookie path with domain name

Comment: Looks like you want to share cookie between domain and subdomain, this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old Code

```
setcookie("traffic_source_1", 1, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
```

Replace WIth

```
setcookie("traffic_source_1", 1, time() + (86400 * 30), "/",".website.com");
```